# Gulp - Managing library dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, gulp

I am working on a project where I have a `vendor` directory containing quite a few libraries and then all the app specific sources in `app/js` directory. I want to use gulp to minify everything in a single file maintaining the dependencies. I can't find a proper way to do so.

Example - Both jQuery UI and Bootstrap requires jQuery to be loaded before them. How do I specify this in my gulp task?

One way I know of is to pass the `gulp.src()` method an array of paths and it will emit the files in that particular order but it seems very unnatural to me.

```
var paths = ['vendor/jquery.min.js', 'vendor/jquery-ui.min.js', 'vendor/bootstrap.min.js']
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src(paths)
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
        ...
        ...
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/all.min.js'))

})
```

For a large number of libraries, it doesn't seem right to include path to specific files that way and pass it to `.src()` method. How can I manage it better? Can `bower` be used in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well like you said, the easiest way is to add them to an array and gulp.src

```
gulp.src([
    'public/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'public/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
    'public/assets/js/my_scripts.js'
    ])
```

So you can just add the path of new js files you want to include.

Another possibility is https://github.com/austinpray/asset-builder

here is an example gulpfile with asset-builder https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Another possibility is to auto-bundle the files from your bower file.
https://truongtx.me/2014/07/18/using-bower-with-gulp/

Comment: For now, I am going to stick to injecting paths in `.src()` but moving to a bower based solution may be what I want in long run.